# Leitura de dados da PNAD 2016

Tags: r

Ao fazer a leitura dos da Pnad 2016, executei o código abaixo, no r studio

```
# Ler o dicionário de variáveis com as posições
#devtools::install_github("tidyverse/readr")

library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

dic = read_xls("dicionario_das_variaveis_PNAD_Continua_microdados.xls", 
skip=4, 
           col_names = F)
dic = dic %>% select(1:3) %>% na.omit
dic$inicio = as.integer(dic$inicio)
names(dic) = c("inicio", "tamanho", "nome")
dic

# Lendo a PNAD
# Primeiro, vamos definir um objeto com o formato das variáveis de interesse
 ?read_fwf
 posicoes = fwf_positions(start = dic$inicio, end = dic$inicio + (dic$tamanho - 1),
                     col_names = dic$nome)
posicoes$begin = posicoes$begin + 1

pnad16.1 = read_fwf("PNADC_012016_20180816.txt", col_positions = posicoes)
```

Mas ao final, o programa não roda e apresenta o erro:

```
Error in guess_types_(datasource, tokenizer, locale, n = guess_max) : 
Begin offset (5) must be smaller than end offset (5)
```

Agradeço ajuda!!

Comment: Danielle, o dicionário que você está utilizando pode não ser deste relatório do PNAD. Experimente baixar o dicionário do mesmo endereço que baixou o Pnad. 

https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/download/DownloadArvore.aspx?f=1&caminho=Trabalho_e_Rendimento/Pesquisa_Nacional_por_Amostra_de_Domicilios_continua/Trimestral/Microdados/2016

Answer (score 3):

Existe um pacote criado para facilitar o download e leitura de microdados do Brasil. O pacote se chama `microdadosBrasil` e ainda não está no CRAN. Para baixá-lo rode:

```
# Precisa ter o pacote devtools instalado
devtools::install_github("lucasmation/microdadosBrasil")
```

Utilizando este pacote ler os dados da PNAD Contínua de 2016 é tão difícil quanto:

```
library(microdadosBrasil)
download_sourceData("PnadContinua", "2016-anual-1v", unzip = TRUE)
pessoas <- read_PNADcontinua("pessoas", "2016-anual-1v")
head(names(pessoas))
```

> [1] "Ano"       "Trimestre" "UF"        "Capital"   "RM_RIDE"  "UPA"

Para conhecer mais opções do pacote veja a documentação da função`?read_PNADcontinua`, ou então visite o README do projeto, disponível em [inglês](https://github.com/lucasmation/microdadosBrasil/blob/master/README.md) ou em [português](https://github.com/lucasmation/microdadosBrasil/blob/master/README_PT.md) (um pouco desatualizado).